# mod_rewrite trailing slash issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use a .htaccess to redirect a domain to a sub directory. The url, "example.com" successfully redirects to "example.com/sub" and "example.com/forums/" will redirect to "example.com/sub/forums", hiding the sub directory "sub" from the address bar. But using "example.com/forums" (no trailing slash) will redirect properly but show example.com/sub/forums in the browser's address bar.

I've tried modifying the htaccess file to add trailing slashes when omitted but that didn't seem to help. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.+) sub/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you requst /forum, the Apache figure out that /forum is not a file, but a directory /forum/, so it emits an external redirect (301 redirect) to the proper url.
What you are going to do is to intercept this behaviour like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.+) sub/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
```

The actual rules may differ, but you get the idea.